# dataflow python - KeyError even though no input to the step and the key exists for matched cases

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a data pipeline to extract 4 types of json which comes with different attribute structure and write it to Bigquery.

**My pipeline :**

```
data =  (pipeline 
                    | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
                )
        
        
        # first branch - push message to Datastore
        p1 =    (data  
                    | "Add publish time" >> ParDo(AddTimestamp()) 
                    | "Create Entity" >> Map(EntityWrapper(known_args.kind).make_entity) 
                    | "Write to Datastore" >> WriteToDatastore(DATASTORE_PROJECT)
        )
        # second branch - write data to Bigquery 
        p2 =    (data  
                    | "classify request depending on type" >> ParDo(ClassifyReq()).with_outputs('label', 'ads', 'website', 'post')
        )

        for type in ['label', 'ads', 'website', 'post'] :
            
            result =   (p2[type] 
                            | "extract req: " + type >> ParDo(ExtractReq(type)) # step label name must be unique
                            | "Write to Bigquery: " + type >> io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                known_args.output_table,
                                schema=known_args.output_schema,
                                write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                )
                        )
```

**My function :**

```
class ClassifyReq(DoFn):
    """
    A transform that classify type of Pub/Sub messages and outputs element with tag
    """
    def process(self,element):
        type = ''
        req_str = str(element)
        req = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
        
        if 'inbox_labels' in req_str:
            type = 'label'
        elif 'ad_id' in req_str:
            type = 'ads'
        elif ('postback' in req_str or 'referral' in req_str) and 'ref' in req_str:
            type = 'website'
        elif ('feed' in req_str) and ('comment' in req_str): # only comment , no reaction_type
            data = req['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']
            from_id = data['from']['id']
            if from_id not in page_data.keys():  # only update not from page admin
                type = 'post'

        yield TaggedOutput(type, element)
class ExtractReq(DoFn):
    """
    A Transform that extract element and map data for Bigquery table depending on 
    given tag from the prior step.
    """
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def process(self, element):
        req = json.loads(element.decode("utf-8"))
        page_id = req['entry'][0]['id']
        if self.type == 'label':
            unix_datetime = req['entry'][0]['time']
            data = req['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']
            customer_id = data['user']['id']
            label = data['label']['page_label_name']
            label_action = data['action']
            row = {'page_id': page_id,
            'type': self.type, 
            'customer_id' : customer_id, 
            'unix_datetime': unix_datetime,
            'ad_data' : None,
            'ad_type' : None,
            'ad_title' : None,
            'post_id': None, 
            'post_link': None,
            'label' : label,
            'action' : label_action
            }
            
        elif self.type == 'ads':
            data = req['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]
            customer_id = data['sender']['id']
            unix_datetime = int(str(req['entry'][0]['time'])[:-3])
            if isinstance(data, str):
                data = json.loads(str)
            ad_id = data['referral']['ad_id']
            ad_title = data['referral']['ads_context_data']['ad_title']
            ad_type = data['referral']['type']
            post_id = data['referral']['ads_context_data']['post_id']
            
            row = {'page_id': page_id,
            'type': self.type, 
            'customer_id' : customer_id, 
            'unix_datetime': unix_datetime,
            'ad_data' : ad_id,
            'ad_type' : ad_type,
            'ad_title' : ad_title,
            'post_id': post_id, 
            'post_link': None,
            'label' : None,
            'action' : None
            }
            
        elif self.type == 'website':
            data = req['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]
            # timestamp has 13 digits so cut out milli second unit
            unix_datetime = int(str(req['entry'][0]['time'])[:-3])
            if isinstance(data, str):
                data = json.loads(str)
            customer_id = data['sender']['id']
            ref = data['referral']['ref']

            row = {'page_id': page_id,
            'type': self.type, 
            'customer_id' : customer_id, 
            'unix_datetime': unix_datetime,
            'ad_data' : ref,
            'ad_type' : None,
            'ad_title' : None,
            'post_id': None, 
            'post_link': None,
            'label' : None,
            'action' : None
            }
           
        elif self.type == 'post':
            data = req['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']
            from_id = data['from']['id']
            link = data['post']['permalink_url']
            post_id = data['post_id']
            unix_datetime = data['created_time']
            verb = data['verb']
            
            row = {'page_id': page_id,
            'type': self.type, 
            'customer_id' : from_id, 
            'unix_datetime': unix_datetime,
            'ad_data' : None,
            'ad_type' : None,
            'ad_title' : None,
            'post_id': post_id, 
            'post_link': link,
            'label' : None,
            'action' : verb
            }
        return [row]
```

My error mostly occured with the type 'website' and 'post. For example

`KeyError: "post [while running 'extract req: post-ptransform-217']"`

`KeyError: "referral [while running 'extract req: website-ptransform-228']"`

I used to manually test with some requests of each type and it works fine and I think the key really exists for each type. Moreover, I've checked that sometimes the first step has no website-typed output yet still error from step extract req: website occured. I have tried to check with `if isinstance(data, str):`  If not use `json.loads(data)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can share with us a little mock to simulate the input ? With a mock I could test more easily your code.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I'm sorry. I've tried to debug again by putting all request into bigquery as well. And found out that it's because that there are many unwanted request from sources which i didn't classify well. Some wrong type of request passed to classificaation and caused errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I struggled for many days, I got a solution to debug my code by writing a request string as one of a column in Bigquery. As there are too many cases of unwanted webhook request, I missed some rules in classification, so they passed the classification without the key I wants to extract.